# Unable to find Spring Reference samples package (org.springframework.samples)

Tags: java, spring

I'am going through the [Spring Reference Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/) and I see that many samples codes refer to artifacts from the package org.springframework.samples. I have been looking for them on Github without success.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is evolving over the years. The examples with **jpetstore** where *PetStoreServiceImpl* was used existed around 2007 - 2009, when Spring 2 - 2.5 was used. It is not maintained any more. The current version of examples is [**petclinic**](https://github.com/spring-petclinic), see the links below. The project close to what you refer is [**spring-framework-petclinic**](http://%20https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-framework-petclinic).

The examples of code and configuration in the Spring documentation were not updated with the time. Even for Spring 5 they still use a lot of XML. Technically speaking XML configuration is fine. But in the last 5 years I haven't see any new Spring project with XML configuration. All of them have used annotations.

Also you see in the documentation *JpaAccountDao*, *JpaItemDao*. It is also not wrong. But very often new Spring applications are based on Spring Boot, Spring Data, and instead of DAO concept the repository concept is used.

Nevertheless, all core concepts in the documentation are still valid and one should know them. For instance, the documentation about scopes uses old screenshots with DAOs. But the text is valid and up to date.

Comment: I'm still struggling, can you locate this class for ewample: `org.springframework.samples.jpetstore.services.PetStoreServiceImpl`

Comment: @acmoune: I have updated he answer.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanations. I am just starting with Spring, and I started with Spring Boot, but I kept feeling that I am ignoring a lot of Core framework realities, so I decided to learn the Core first. Like you said: `...one should know them`. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you check this https://www.reddit.com/r/springframework/comments/h9zofx/what_is_the_best_bookresource_to_learn_the_latest/

Comment: So what is your question now?

Comment: It is not a valid StackOverflow question, that is why I pushed it to Reddit. But it is all right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc

You can find it in [Spring Github](https://github.com/spring-projects)